# Adns.py python asynchronous interface setting timeout

Tags: python

I have been trying to search how to perform a customizable timeout not using exceptions, alarms, sockets and not killing threads but just modifying **timeout parameter** via python interface in Andy Dustman code: http://code.google.com/p/adns-python/

I have found some links like: http://www.filefactory.com/file/cb5b905/n/Links.txt

Please, Could someone give me a hand with this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO! Please do not post links to dubious file-sharing sites. Instead, post the links directly in your question. Also, your question is somewhat unspecific. What have tried so far? With which specific part are you having problems?

Comment: I tried but I was linking too many links and because of my short joining in this blog, I hadn´t got permissions to post it. Thanks for your advice